# how to dynamic resize table view controller on ipad?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uitableview

I have controllers with 2 columns like on image:

[image: ipad view]

On the left is `Table View` in `Table Border`. On the right is `Text View`.

I need to allow users to resize width of left column (`Table View`). I mean that i can click or touch on vertical seperate line between left and right column and move it to change width.

How to do that?

I found solution to user someone's split view controller like https://github.com/xsirjay/MGSplitViewController , but it is hard for me to figure out code to resize views only and clear all rest not required code.

Comment: yeah!!! best way to doing what you want is split view controller,
put split view controller in to view and in left side put table view and in right side text view...what's the problem then.

Answer (score 0):

You should set in the .xib the layout for autoresizing of your tableview to

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACsUQ.png]

so it will automaticaly change it's frame if the parent view resize

Comment: > it will automaticaly change it's frame if the parent view resize. BUT how to change parent view resize with my finger on ipad or mouse?

Comment: take a look at the `MGSplitDividerView` and the `- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method. if you analyze the project you will the magic behind ;)